# Can't start a process using Mono under Ubuntu

Tags: unix, ubuntu, mono

I'm getting this exception when trying to start a process: `Native error= Cannot find the specified file`
However, the specified binary file *does* exist. Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened due to missing executable attribute on this binary file.